# Convert array of number and object into array of number

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an array in my Angular class containing number and object as shown below.

What I want to do is recreate the array with only number like so [5,8,9,1,7] i.e. I get the id of the object inside the array and append it to the array.

```
allowedDepartmentAccess = [
    5,
    8,
    9,
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Human Resource",
        "abbreviation": "HR"
    },
    {
        "id": 7,
        "name": "Warehouse",
        "abbreviation": "WH"
    }
]
```

Comment: If possible, I'd try to fix the underlying problem that led to this mess in the first place.

Comment: you see I am using dual list, when I add a new item to the allowed array, it is in the form of object. But the previous entered values are in form of number.